# aria attribute for Static text

Tags: android, html, wai-aria

```html
<p class="ht-inner-header" id="hlpt_Heading" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0" title="Mobile data: SIM Card Required" style="outline: none;" aria-live="assertive"><span aria-hidden="true">Mobile data: SIM Card Required</span></p>
```

My above code reads as "Mobile data: SIM Card Required" "Double Tap to activate".

Its a static text I DONT WANT "Double Tap to activate". I tried role= "text" but no help..

Comment: There is no "Double Tap to activate" in the code you provided

Comment: Its from device talkback

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `tabindex`.

`tabindex` tells the browser (I assume you are using an embedded browser in your app) that it is a control. When you have TalkBack running, it reminds you that you need to double-tap (instead of single-tap) controls when they are focused. Changing its `role` will not make it stop being an interactive control.

Unrelated, is the `title` meant to make up for the text you have hidden in the `<span aria-hidden="true">`? If so, that is an odd way to address the accessible name calculation. I suggest you dump both the `<span aria-hidden="true">` and the `title`.